How to identify if a field vector is dictionary encoded
We are implementing an Arrow Flight client in Java. Is there a standard way that Flight servers use to indicate that a particular Field Vector is dictionary encoded. We are trying to make the Flight client be compatible with different types of Flight server.
FieldVector vector = vectorSchemaRoot.getVector(columnIndex);
vector.getField().getDictionary()

I can see there is a method to get the dictionary encoding of a field. Can we assume that if the dictionary encoding is set, then the field is dictionary encoded and if dictionary encoding is null the field is not encoded?

Dictionary encoding is part of the type, so yes, you would check the field metadata. There's nothing specific to Flight in this.
